# Frechet derivative of $\delta_{x(t)}$ is $\delta_{x'(t)}$?

Tags: measure-theory, frechet-derivative

I don't really know anything about the Fréchet derivative but I was wondering if the Fréchet derivative of $\delta_{x(t)}$ was $\delta_{x'(t)}$. More precisely, if we consider the Banach space $(\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d), \|\cdot\|_{\text{TV}})$ of signed measures with total variation norm, $t\mapsto x(t)$ is a smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $\delta_{x(t)}$ the Dirac measure in the point $x(t)$ and consider the map
\begin{align}
\mathbb{R}\to&\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)\\
t\mapsto& \delta_{x(t)}
\end{align}

I was wondering if this is Frechet differentiable and if like intuition suggest we have that it's Frechet derivative at point $t$ is $\delta_{x'(t)}$. I think that what I have to verify is (is it?) that $$\frac{\|\delta_{x(t+h)}-\delta_{x(t)}-h\delta_{x'(t)}\|_{\text{TV}}}{|h|}\to0\text{ when }h\to 0$$

Comment: Technically you could interpret that as a "Fréchet derivative", but since its domain is just an interval, there is no need for such functional analytic big words. That's just a derivative, defined as the limit of the differential ratio, as you rightfully point out.

Comment: When the domain is an interval, you usually just say "derivative" or "tangent vector." And yes, if $f$ is a function defined on some interval with values on some normed vector space, then $f'(t)$ is defined as you would have in calculus 101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider any smooth function $x:(-1,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x(t)\neq x'(t)$ and $\|x'(t)\|>0$.
The measure(s)
$$\mu_h:= \frac{1}{h}\Big(\delta_{x(t+h)}-\delta_{x(t)}-h\delta_{x'(t)}\Big)$$
have in principle total variation $\frac{2}{|h|}+1\not\rightarrow0$ as $h\rightarrow0$. Indeed, the variation measure $|\mu|=\mu_+ + \mu_-$ is given by
$$|\mu_h|=\frac{1}{|h|}\Big(\delta_{x(t+h)}+\delta_{x(t)}+|h|\delta_{x'(t)}\Big)$$

Even in the simple case of $x_c(t)\equiv \mathbf{c}$ for some $\mathbf{c}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ the anger is not:

$$\mu_h:=\frac{1}{h}\Big(\delta_{x_c(t+h)}-\delta_{x_c(t)}-h\delta_{x_c'(t)}\Big)=-\delta_{\mathbf{0}}$$
and so, $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\mu_h=-\delta_{\mathbf{0}}\neq0$

---

It seems that the appropriate setting would be (weak) convergence with respect a space of smooth functions, maybe $\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^b)$, or the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

For example, if $\phi$ is continuously differentiable and $\nu_{t,h}=\frac{1}{h}(\delta_{x(t+h)}-\delta_{x(t)})$, then
$$\nu_h\phi(t):=\frac{1}{h}(\phi(x(t+h))-\phi(x(t))\xrightarrow{h\rightarrow0}\phi'(x(t))x'(t)=x'(t)\delta_{x(t)}D\phi$$
where $D$ is the derivative operator acting on $\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. From this, one can see that the space of measures $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ of finite total variation is not big enough to hold the (weak) limit $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\nu_{t,h}$.

Comment: thank you. What exactly does "other kinds of differentiability are not appropriate here either since the dual space $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})^n=C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ does not behave well under differentiation"? Also, when we say that the appropriate setting would be something like weak convergence with respect to a space of smooth functions it means $\int\phi d\mu_h \to\int\phi d\delta_{x'(t)}$ for every $\phi$ smooth?

Comment: I am not so used to this notation. When you write $\mu\phi$ for a measure $\mu$, this is like $\langle\mu,\phi\rangle=\int \phi d\mu$? I am not sure I understand why in the last equality we don't have $x'(t)\langle\delta_{x(t)},\phi'\rangle$ (with $\phi'$ instead of $\phi$)

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it, isn't $x'(t)\delta_{x(t)}\phi=x'(t)\int\phi d\delta_{x(t)}=x'(t)\phi(x(t))$ so we have $\phi$ instead of $\phi'$?

Comment: @edamondo: you are right, I got a little carried away. The right limit is $x'(t)\phi'(x(t))$. In other to write this in terms of functionals, the weak" derivative is $x'(t)\delta_{x(t)} D$, where $D$ is the differential operator on $\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. That is the reason why the space of measure is too small in this case to handle differentiation.

Comment: Oh, I see. the limit is $x'(t)\delta_{x(t)}'$ where $\delta_a'$ is not a measure but a distribution, which is the distributional derivative of $\delta_a$. But I am still struggling to understand why Gateau derivative or Hadamard derivative (the latter I don't know) has something to do with the fact that $\mathcal{M}$ is the dual of $C_0$.

Comment: The directional derivative (which is more or less what the Gateaux and Hadamard derivatives are)  coincide with the Frecehet derivative (should it were to exist) for functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $X$ (a Banach space). The reason I brough-up the dual is because  in your setting $X=\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with TV distance, it is natural to let measures act on its dual.

Comment: +1, but the answer would be even better by writing $\delta'_{x'(t)}$ instead of $\delta_{x'(t)} D$

Answer (score 2):

Technicalities aside (see comments to the main question), I don't think the result is correct. Take an arbitrary continuous function $f$. You can pair it with that $\delta_{x(t)}$ and the result is $$\tag{1}\langle \delta_{x(t)}, f\rangle = f(x(t)).$$ Now, if $\delta_{x(t)}$ was differentiable, whatever that means, it MUST imply that the left-hand side of (1) is a differentiable real-valued function of $t$. But this is not the case, because the function $f$ is just a generic continuous function, it needs not be differentiable at any point.

Comment: The "whatever that means" is precisely defined in the question as the map $t\mapsto \delta_{x(t)}$ between Banach spaces being Frechét-differentiable. The "MUST imply that $\langle \delta_{x(t)}, f\rangle$ is a differentiable expression in $t$" is completely unclear to me. Why would one factor of a pairing being differentiable in $t$ imply that the pairing with a non-differentiable second factor has to be differentiable?

Comment: @Christoph: Because the second factor is a constant. The map $\mu\mapsto \langle\mu, f\rangle$, where $f$ is a fixed continuous function, is a bounded linear operator on $\mathcal M$. Any notion of differentiability in vector spaces must commute with bounded linear operators.

Comment: Right, I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure what it means and how you use the fact "Any notion of differentiability in vector spaces must commute with bounded linear operators"

Comment: @edamondo: See Lang, "Undergraduate analysis", chapter XVII, corollary 3.2 https://books.google.com/books?id=7oDSBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&hl=es&pg=PR14#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1):

To find the derivative (if it exists) we have to consider the measure
$$
\frac{\delta_{x(t+h)}-\delta_{x(t)}}{h}\quad\text{given by}\quad A\mapsto
\frac 1 h \cdot \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x(t+h)\in A$, $x(t)\notin A$}, \\
-1 & \text{if $x(t+h)\notin A$, $x(t)\in A$}, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Claiming that this would converge to $\delta_{x'(t)}$ as $h\to 0$ would mean this measure converges to
$$
A\mapsto \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x'(t)\in A$}, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
You could check this by computing the total variation of the difference, but it should be rather obvious that this isn't the case and the first measure above does not converge for $h\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I found that the total variation between the two measures is $3$ for each $h>0$. Now I am wondering if there are other norms (weak convergence norm maybe?) for which we have the convergence.

Comment: I don't think so, the limit under any norm won't change when reparametrizing the curve $x(t)$, but $x'(t)$ does, so it can't appear in this setting at all.

Answer (score 0):

For a very different perspective we have the following result: **the tangent vector of the curve $t \mapsto \delta_{x(t)}$ at a point $s$ is $\delta_{x'(s)}$** provided $x$ is absolutely continuous (and hence differentiable almost everywhere).

Here is what I mean by tangent vector (for a detailed treatment you have to consult Ambrosio, Savaré and Gigli's book: *Gradient flows in metric spaces and in the space of probability measures* or the PhD Thesis of Nicolá Gigli (*On the geometry of the space of probability measures endowed with the quadratic optimal transport distance*), available [on his website](https://cvgmt.sns.it/person/226/)).

Let $P_2(X)$ be the set of [Radon measures on $X$ with finite second moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Definition) and $I \subset \mathbb R$ be an interval open to the right.

> **Definition 1 (Tangent vector).** A tangent vector to a curve $\gamma \colon I \to P_2(\mathbb R^d)$ at $t \in I$ is a "velocity plan" $v_t \in T_{\gamma(t)} P_2(\mathbb R^d)$ such that for every $v_{t, h} \in \exp_{\gamma(t)}^{-1}(\gamma(t + h))$, $h > 0$ we have
> \begin{equation*}
>         \lim_{h \searrow 0} W_{\gamma(t)}\left(v_t, \frac{1}{h} v_{t, h}\right)
>         = 0,
>     \end{equation*}
> that is, $v_t = \lim_{h \searrow 0} v_{t, h}$ with respect to $W_{\gamma(t)}$.

Let me give some explanations for all the notations: the space $T_{\gamma(t)} P_2(\mathbb R^d)$ is a sort of *"geometric" tangent space* of $P_2(\mathbb R^d)$ at $\gamma(t)$.
In the case of $\gamma(t) = \delta_{x(t)}$ we have $T_{\gamma(t)} P_2(\mathbb R^d) = \{ \gamma(t) \otimes \nu: \nu \in P_2(\mathbb R^d) \}$.

Further, $W_{\gamma(t)}$ is a [Wasserstein-2-type metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Definition) on measures of the form $\gamma(t) \otimes \mu$ ("fixed base measure $\gamma(t)$").

Next, for a constant $c > 0$ and a measure $\mu \in P_2(\mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^d)$, we define $c \cdot \mu := (\pi_1, c \cdot \pi_2)_{\#} \mu$, where $\pi_j \colon \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$, $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto x_j$  are the projections onto the $j$-th component for $j \in \{ 1, 2 \}$ and $\#$ is the [pushforward of measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Definition).

Lastly, $\exp_{\gamma(t)}^{-1}\big( \gamma(t + h) \big)$ is the inverse of a suitably chosen exponential map (this makes sense since $P_2(\mathbb R^d)$ behaves similarly to an infinite-dimensional Riemannian manifold). In the case of a curve of Diracs, like here, it is simply equal to $ \left\{ \gamma(t) \otimes \delta_{\{ x(t + h) - x(t) \}} \right\}$, so that $$\frac{1}{h} v_{t, h} = \gamma(t) \otimes \delta_{\left\{ \frac{x(t + h) - x(t)}{h} \right\}} \xrightarrow[W_{\gamma(t)}]{h \searrow 0} \gamma(t) \otimes \delta_{\{ x'(t) \}}.$$